# Fragments and garbage collector

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a problem with garbage collection (I think).
Let me explain:

This is a simplified version of my activity:

```
public Fragment fragA;
public Fragment fragB;

private FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragA = new FragA();

        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();       
        transaction.add(R.id.container, fragA);
        transaction.commit();           
    }
}

//A USER CLICK ON A BUTTON (in fragment A) TO SHOW FRAGMENT B:
public void showFragB() {
        fragB = new FragB();

        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();       
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragA);
        transaction.commit();
}

//A USER CLICK ON A BUTTON (in fragment B) TO DO SOME ACTIONS THAT REQUIRE fragA:
public void doSomethingWithFragA() {
        if (fragA == null)
            Log.d("TAG", "WTF HAPPENS!?"
        else
            Log.d("TAG", "great, we can do the action"
}
```

Now, most of the times this thing works fine.
The problem is... IF I OPEN THE APP, PRESS THE BUTTON (in fragment A) TO SHOW FRAGMENT B, PRESS HOME BUTTON (and do something that requires ram like browsing or see youtube videos), RETURN TO MY APP, PRESS THE OTHER BUTTON (in fragment B)...fragA IS null!!!

But the app is not totally recreated because when i return to it, fragment B is visible like the app never closes itself.

So...can you explain me this behaviour and how to fix it?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is with your code, but I *doubt* it is the garbage collector.

Comment: And why should `fragA` point to a object? In your current code/pseudocode you initialize fragA in the `onCreate()` method *only* when the `savedInstanceState` is null(which will not be the case if the activity is being recreated).

Comment: If the object were destroyed too early there would be no reason to assign the value to null. null is itself a value and not a lack of value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the app is not totally recreated because when i return to it,
>   fragment B is visible like the app never closes itself.

That is false. It is possible that your app is completely recreated, but `fragB` will be reloaded by the system because it were attached to a container at the moment of the home button pressed (in this case R.id.container).

In the described scenario `savedInstanceState` is not null, so your code won't create `fragA`. It is important to note that only attached fragments recreated automatically, but you removed `fragA` with a replace so it won't be recreated by the system neither. (Replace detaches every fragment attached to that container, and attach the new fragment after.)

There are several solutions for this problem, but I think the most elegant is to set `fragA` as a target fragment:

```
public void showFragB() {
    fragB = new FragB();

    // this line will force the system to recreate fragA,
    // if fragB is recreated;
    fragB.setTargetFragment(fragA, 0);  

    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction(); 

    // I assumed fragA here is just a typo (it should be fragB)      
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragA);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Then you can use `getTargetFragment` in `fragB` to get reference to `fragA`.

**Important:**

You realized that `fragA` is null, but actually `fragB` is null too, you just never use that reference in your code.

The reason is that the system just recreates the fragments for you, but officially that won't make your `fragA`, `fragB`, etc... references point to the actual recreated fragments (neither if the fragment is visible). You have to do this manually:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    fragA = new FragA();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();       
    transaction.add(R.id.container, fragA, "TAG_TO_FIND_FRAG_A");
    transaction.commit();           
}
else{
    fragA = manager.findFragmentByTag("TAG_TO_FIND_FRAG_A");

    if(fragA == null){
        // fragA was not attached so the system have not reacreted it
    } else {
        // fragA was attached!
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- `fragB`'s reference should be set just like I did with `fragA` above.
- You can reproduce the problem with a rotation in this case. It is
  much easier.
- Read the whole [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) on fragments!

Answer (score 0):

well i guess the `GC` has nothing to do with your issue, what you can do, is to follow the `LifeCycle`

```
@Override onPause() & onStop // and see what happens.
```

,check out this link for more info [Android Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)